# Is GCPD's bullet giving ritual is based on real life or is it from comics?

Tags: realism, comic-adaptation, gotham

In *Gotham* S04E08 we see GCPD have a ritual of distributing bullet caps to the surviving officers. Is this ritual based on some real thing or is it from DC comics?

Comment: They were presented with the bullet that was pulled from their body